# inspect an xml file, and generate a report on duplicate elements using xslt-3

Tags: xslt-3.0

Given the following xml as input, i try to create a report using xslt-3

```
<breakfast_menu>
    <food>
        <name>01</name>
        <price>$5.95</price>
        <description>Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple [syrup]</description>
        <calories>650</calories>
    </food>
    <food>
        <name>01</name>
        <price>$7.95</price>
        <description>Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple [syrup]</description>
        <calories>350</calories>
    </food>
    <food>
        <name>02</name>
        <price>$8.95</price>
        <description>Light Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh berries and whipped cream</description>
        <calories>900</calories>
    </food>
    <food>
        <name>03</name>
        <price>$4.50</price>
        <description>Thick slices made from our homemade sourdough bread</description>
    </food>
    <food>
        <name>04</name>
        <price>$6.95</price>
        <description>Light Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh berries and whipped cream</description>
        <calories>100</calories>
    </food>
    <food>
        <name>05</name>
        <price>$7.95</price>
        <description>Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple [syrup]</description>
        <calories>250</calories>
    </food>
</breakfast_menu>
```

to identify all menu elements, that have the same description.

Please note that not all menu nodes have a calories element, thus a null text value may be inserted in the generated corresponding tab column.

From the above example, i try to create a tsv report that would look like (sorted by the description element):

```
01\tTwo of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple [syrup]\t650
01\tTwo of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple [syrup]\t350
05\tTwo of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple [syrup]\t250
02\tLight Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh berries and whipped cream\t900
02\tLight Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh berries and whipped cream\t100
```

my trial using xsl v2:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"

  exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="ids" match="*[@description]" use="@description"/> 

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <duplicates>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//*[@description]"/>
    </duplicates>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="*[@description]">
    <xsl:if test="count(key('ids', @description)) &gt; 1">
      <duplicate 
        id="{@description}" 
        dup-count="{count(key('ids', @description))}" 
        node-xpath="{string-join((for $node in ancestor::* return concat($node/name(),'[', count($node/preceding-sibling::*[name() = $node/name()])+1, ']'),concat(name(),'[', count(preceding-sibling::*[name() = current()/name()]) + 1, ']')
   ),'/')}">

      </duplicate>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your wanted output format seems to be plain text, yet your XSLT creates an XML document with a `duplicates` root element and then with `duplicate` child elements only having attributes. And while you say you use XSLT 2 and want to use XSLT 3 you don't use `for-each-group` to identify duplicates but a key. Furthermore you say you want to sort the duplicates by `description` but you have items starting with `Two` before the ones starting with `Light`. So you need to clarify your requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `for-each-group` to `group-by="description"`, then you can output the text format using `value-of separator="&#9;"`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0">


  <xsl:output method="text" />

  <xsl:template match="breakfast_menu">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="food" group-by="description">
          <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"/>
          <xsl:if test="current-group()[2]">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
          </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="food">
      <xsl:value-of select="name, description, string(calories)" separator="&#9;"/>
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBsV

Comment: excellent, a minor modification, how could one have in the report, say in the first line, a number indicating the number of description that are found more than one time? In the above question, the result would be 3

Comment: I am not sure what the `3` you mention relates to. If you want to output the items in a group you can use `count(current-group())` like I have done in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBsV/1 with `<xsl:value-of select="count(current-group()), name, description, string(calories)" separator="&#9;"/>`. If that doesn't help then ask a new question.

Comment: no, what i need is just a number, something like for all groups found, sum up the (count(current-group()) -1). The sum will have as output how many times each description is found to be occurring more than once, thus in the above example one gets 3 as a result

Comment: Please ask a new question, if you want to count or sum up all groups you need to store the result of the grouping first in some way, which is certainly possible but not something that belongs into a comment to this question.

Comment: you are correct, my mistake: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50331888/sum-of-count-in-xslt-3